# IE8 scrolls down on ajax onload event

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I have trouble with this page for example: http://www.last.cz/exotika.html. If you open it in FF or chrome, you start at the top of page. But when you try in IE8, it loads scrolled past the header. Compatibility mode does not help. I think the filter details that get filled by onload function cause it. Does anyone who ran into the same problem know how to fix it? A css hack would work I guess.

Thanks for suggestions. Mike

Comment: I would suggest using firebug light for IE or debugbar to see what the dom reading really is since IE reads doms a bit differently than gecko.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be executed onload(placed in core.js):

```
$('#item0').focus()
```

That's what happens, the element #item0 gets the focus and the page scrolls down to fully show the element(it will scroll until the bottom-border of the first "hotel-box"--thats what #item0 actually is-- occurs inside the viewport).

Other browsers may ignore the instruction because the element is a `<div/>` and can not be focused.

Comment: thanks, found it and fixed it in the morning. the first item in the list had that id. did you actually find it in the minified script? props!

Comment: Found it in the minified script, I was looking for the string showList(the function called onload, the name of the function seems suspect to me, and there was the instruction :) )